# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object( OPENSHIFT )

Tags: php, mysqli, openshift

Getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

while pushing new data to my openshit application.

```
function createAppInfo($title,$blog_link,$job_link,$description,$author,$status){

        $db = dbopen();
        $title = $db->real_escape_string($title);
        $author = $db->real_escape_string($author);
        $description = $db->real_escape_string($description);
        $job_link = $db->real_escape_string($job_link);
        $blog_link = $db->real_escape_string($blog_link);
        $status = $db->real_escape_string($status);

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `app`(title,blog_link,job_link,description,author,status) 
            values('$title','$blog_link','$job_link','$description','$author','$status')");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$title,$blog_link,$job_link,$description,$author,$status);   // bind inputs to the parameter

        /* execute prepared statement */
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    }
```

This is the code i am running, but it seems to me that `Openshift` is bloacking prepare or prepare is not working correctly i dont know..cause the code is working on local machine.
Also, its i change it to regular `$db-query(INSERT)` its working absolutely fine.

**UPDATE:**

**dbcon.php** file

```
<?php
function dbopen(){
  $host="localhost"; // Host name 
  $username="**"; // Mysql username 
  $password="**"; // Mysql password 
  $db_name="***"; // Database name 

 $db= new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
  if (!$db)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  return($db);
}?>
```

I am including this file to call dbopen()

Comment: And where is your connection?

Comment: You have missed something between execute and bind_param.

Comment: @sectus I have no clue what i am missing.

Comment: @Abhinay, I do no know... but it is not $stmt->close();

Comment: offtopic? whats the use of `bind_param` when they are hard coded? Maybe thats your problem is you use both and `bind_param` doesn't know what to bind to?

Comment: so much for prepared statements

Comment: @Class I dont understand your point..are you saying its not the way this code should be or something else..i have no experience with prepare and bind params. could you please explain

Comment: @sectus I have checked documentation just now..its the same prepare, bind and execute..could you please tell me what it is that i am missing

Comment: try changeing this `values('$title','$blog_link','$job_link','$description','$author','$status')` to `values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` because it might because the `bind_param` has no placeholders in the query and parameters need to be `:str` or `?`. Also all of `$title = $db->real_escape_string($title);` can be removed if using prepared statements.

Comment: @Ghost still its working on local machine.

Comment: @Class OK,will be back in a mint..let me try this

Comment: EDIT change/remove the `bind_param` and just have `execute` like `$stmt->execute(array($title,$blog_link,$job_link,$description,$author,$status));`

Comment: @Class this is what i am getting: PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables..do i have to add date also..cause I have date attribute in my DB but it auto updates with timstamp..i dont know does that make sense ?

Comment: @Class OK let me try this one

Comment: on using this $stmt->execute(array(..)) its the syntax error:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\xe2\x80\x8c'

Comment: @Class Thanks for your try, but how come its working fine on my local machine and the same code is giving error on server ?

Comment: @Abhinay could be the text file is created in windows and server uses linux and usually use different ways to represent enter/tabs and/or your file might have a BOM?

Comment: yeah I am aslo on linux.

Answer (score 0):

1. see http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php , there aren't as many parameters...
2. see @class comment: why bindparam for parameters that you already included in your request?

So maybe trying smthg like this should help? :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `app` (title,blog_link,job_link,description,author,status)  values(:title,:blog_link,:job_link,:description,:author,:status)");
$stmt->bind_param(':title',$title);
$stmt->bind_param(':blog_link', $blog_link);
etc...
$stmt->execute();
```

or simply let your `prepare` like you did, but forget about `bind_param` (but previous solution should be safer).

Comment: I think the problem is not just the way I am writing code cause its working absolutely fine on local machine.

Comment: then you should tell php.net to modify official documentation to match your local machine... it's a mystery for me if this [`$stmt->bind_param('s',$title,$blog_link,$job_link,$description,$author,$status);`] works where this [`public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )`] is awaited ;-)  (see already quoted dcumentation link.).

Comment: sorry i just realized you where using a "bind_param" function I don't know about, where I refered to "PDOStatement::bindParam" , without underscore. But looking to http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php indicates your first parameter 's' is bad, it shall declare the type of ALL following parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to use `real_escape_string` at all, prepared statements escapes all values automatically. Secondly, when binding your parameters, you need to specify the type for each (answer below assumes all are strings).

**EDIT :**
Upon doing some research, you must use the environment variables in the [MYSQL cartridge](https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html) when establishing a connection through openshift.

**dbcon.php:**

```
<?php
function dbopen(){

define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

 $db= new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  if (!$db)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  return($db);
}?>
```

**MYSQL Query:**

```
$db = dbopen();
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `app`(title,blog_link,job_link,description,author,status)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$title,$blog_link,$job_link,$description,$author,$status);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Getting: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: I have even tried to echo each of them right before this prepare stmt and it is showing the correct data.

Comment: @Class according to his tag is using mysqli.

Comment: @Abhinay what is the dbopen() function?

Comment: I believe the problem is with your db connection. You are using the dbopen() function however have not passed an argument for it. Try my updated answer.

Comment: then `prepare` would fail if it were a db connection problem

Comment: Ok, still try the connection inside the function to rule out and issue with dbopen().

Comment: I have tried adding the same inside this function,
its the same error, call to member function on non-object.

Comment: One more thing, if its really an issue with dbopen(), then how it is working on my system. ideally it should be the same everywhere

Comment: Must be due to openshift but I don't know anything about it.